# Mysql query select takes lots of time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have a site in Laravel that does the following SQL queries, and combined they take like 1.8 seconds. The execution time is taken from the profiler toolbar

```
675.81ms    
SELECT definitions.*, terms.term, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(tags.name) SEPARATOR ",") AS tags FROM definitions INNER JOIN terms ON terms.id = definitions.term_id LEFT JOIN definition_tag ON definitions.id = definition_tag.definition_id LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = definition_tag.tag_id WHERE approved = 1 GROUP BY definitions.id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 2
0.21ms  
SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE `name` = 'no_homepage_random' LIMIT 1
636.11ms    
SELECT definitions.*, terms.term, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(tags.name) SEPARATOR ",") AS tags FROM definitions INNER JOIN terms ON terms.id = definitions.term_id LEFT JOIN definition_tag ON definitions.id = definition_tag.definition_id LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = definition_tag.tag_id WHERE approved = 1 GROUP BY definitions.id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
628.68ms    
SELECT definitions.*, terms.term, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(tags.name) SEPARATOR ",") AS tags FROM definitions INNER JOIN terms ON terms.id = definitions.term_id LEFT JOIN definition_tag ON definitions.id = definition_tag.definition_id LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = definition_tag.tag_id WHERE approved = 1 GROUP BY definitions.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
```

I want to speed up sql queries in general, and also im kinda confused why it only  takes 0.0049 seg running the same queries in phpmyadmin. Website is in a shared hosting.
What can I do to improve?

Comment: Is this a regular issue?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes, the excecution is always slow. Definitions table has about 2000 rows.

Comment: Did you test the queries multiple times in phpMyAdmin? Are they always (a lot) faster?

Comment: In PHP are you including the time used to process the results?

Comment: A quick note, Check your apache log for any delays.

Comment: Without knowing your DB schema, indexes, etc there's no meaningful answer we can really give.  All I can do is make general suggestions: Execute the queries above with EXPLAIN to determine where the bottlenecks are, find where indexes may improve the query performance and add them, refactor your data to make it more easily queried in the way you want to query it, don't rely on Laraval to build a decent query and craft it yourself, etc.

Answer (score 1):

-If your database is not indexed, queries tend to be slow as your database grows bigger and bigger.

-Also look at how you are querying. Make sure there are not so many loops or actions until the query is done.

Answer (score 0):

May be what makes your request takes lots of time is the inner and left join command: In one of the tables : definitions,terms,definition_tag and tags there is a redundancy in the field and using the inner and left join will make your request takes a lot of time.